# how to translate throttle in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, throttling

I am using Laravel 5.7 version. I am using `throttle` in `Kernel.php` to avoid user to send queries more than 60. I would like to translate its message "Too Many Attempts." and use own message. how can I do it in laravel? Where can I find that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Laravel exception handler you can handle that exception before rendering and replace that exception with your custom exception.

In **app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```php
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response|\Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof ThrottleRequestsException) {
        return parent::render(
            $request, new ThrottleRequestsException(
                'Your message',
                $exception->getPrevious(),
                $exception->getHeaders(),
                $exception->getCode()
            )
        );
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException;

if($exception instanceof HttpException && $exception->getStatusCode() == 429) {
return response()->json([
'message' => 'Too Many Attempts',
'code' => 429
], 429)->withHeaders($exception->getHeaders());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create your custom Middleware in the `app/Http/Middlewares` folder, extend the base `\Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests` class and override the `buildException` method ([original implementation here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.7/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php#L114)).

Then assign `throttle` Middleware to your custom Middleware class in `Kernel.php`